# Block animations during loading phase (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

Based on a previous question I decided to upgrade to Angular 1.1.4 and try out of the animation system. I am having trouble doing something I did before. When a user clicks on an element it is added to an ng-repeat element. The animation for this element then scrolls the container to a suitable position to show the element. That part works okay.

There are also times when I'm replacing all the elements and I don't want the scrolling behaviour to happen. Previously I managed this by putting a variable in the scope and in my custom directive looking at that variable. I would then just put a timeout to toggle the variable after loading. Now with the animation system the timeout no longer works.

I need a way to turn on/off certain parts of animations during certain activities of my program. How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing this is a problem too. It causes flickering with ng-show/hide examples because they trigger the transition events during loading.